# How do I write tests for a graphics library?

Tags: unit-testing, graphics, integration-testing

I'm writing an OpenGL 2D library in Python. Everything is going great, and the codebase is steadily growing.

Now I want to write unit tests so I don't accidently bring in new bugs while fixing others/making new features. But I have no idea how those would work with graphics libraries.

Some things I thought of:

- make reference screenshots and compare them with autogenerated screenshots in the tests
- replace opengl calls with logging statements and compare logs

But both seem a bad idea. What is the common way to test graphics libraries?

Comment: The two things you've suggested make pretty sense to me, as long as you are sure there are true results with which to compare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach I have used in the past for component level testing is:

- Use a uniform colored background, with a few different colors.
- Use uniform colored rectangles as graphical objects in tests (with a few different colors).
- Place rectangles in known places where you can calculate their projected position in the image by yourself.
- Calculate expected intensity of each channel of each pixel (background, foreground or mixture).
- If you have a test scenario that results in non-round positions, use a non-accurate compare (e.g. correlation)
- Use calculations to create expected result images.
- Compare output images to expected result images.
- If you have a blur effect, compare sum of intensity instead of discrete intensities.

As graham stated, internal units may be unit-testable free from graphics calls.

Comment: Those are acceptance tests, and they are important, but you will also need the unit tests, as Graham Reeds said in the other answer.

Comment: These are not acceptance tests, these tests test a single component and are either integration tests or unit tests depending on the definition of the unit under test. If the graphical algorithms are written within shaders or in OPENGL/DirectX code, then the code is not always testable separate from the graphics rendering process and this is the only way to "unit" test it.

Comment: @RadomirDopieralski Acceptance tests would be to make sure you can see something and wouldn't consider **exact positions**, **white-box** flows, every single type of **pixel format**, affect of filter effects and etc. System tests would already include application above the graphics engine.

Answer (score 2):

Break it down even further.

The calls that make the graphics will rely on algorithms - test the algorithms.

Comment: Actually, in my case that's only half true. Despite having almost all basic functionality I only use one algorithm (in sorting sprites for batched rendering) and some things like singleton patterns. Almost all other code is straightforward making OpenGL calls accessible.

Comment: Singletons are evil! A contract I worked at used nearly a dozen of them. Made testing a nightmare. In C++ we created a couple of templated functions that allowed you to pull in fake or real loggers etc. to make testing possible. Dunno if you can do that in Python.